# Syntax error calling method with argument

Tags: objective-c, methods, arguments

I am trying to call a method that takes an argument and do not have syntax right.  Can someone see what I am doing wrong?  The precise error is "Use of Undeclared Identifier 'self'".

```
- (NSString*)uniquePicName:(NSString *)extensionString
{
    // Extension string is like @".png"

    NSDate *time = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter* df = [NSDateFormatter new];
    [df setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy-hh-mm-ss"];
    NSString *timeString = [df stringFromDate:time];
    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"File-%@%@", timeString, extensionString];

    return fileName;
}

NSString *extension = @".png";
NSString *newName = [self uniquePicName:extension]//throws error here
```

Comment: Please close your code with brackets. Look like you place } 4 lines above, put it in end of your code.

Comment: where is the call placed in the module ? show its enclosing method.

Comment: Evgeniy the last two lines are not part of the method so they belong outside the brackets no in.  Yves the call is placed in line NSString *newName = [self uniquePicName:extension] where the syntax error occurs.

Comment: @user1904273 when you try to access  self.someProperty in other place of your implementation file, is there any error?

Comment: @user1904273 You can't just stick code anywhere. The last two lines are out of place.

Comment: Ok. That was error.  The two lines were supposed to be in another method but were not.  Got confused by the error referring to "self".  Much obliged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statements:

```
NSString *extension = @".png";
NSString *newName = [self uniquePicName:extension];
```

must be in a method of the class.

If the statements are not in a method `self` does not exist and you get the message: "Use of Undeclared Identifier 'self'".

Comment: Yes that was it.  Thanks for interpreting the self error as it threw me off.